# Bunch of Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue once per day

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

We are seeing tens of `Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue` errors in HTTPERR file every day (and *once that day*) fired in quick succession for our ASP.NET WebAPI application running in IIS 7. We think there is a connection between those and timeouts we are seeing in our HTTP client for this service.

We wonder whether those connection abandonments (that actually happens throughout whole day, separated by few minutes) originates in *client* stops responding, or whether it's the *server* process that freezes, fails to respond and gets cleaned at the end of the day.

Is it possible that a HTTP client that goes silent and not ACK returned data makes IIS wait for such a long time before some cleaning manifests itself by `Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue` log message?